# ¿Cómo hacer que el condicional funcione correctamente?

Tags: java, condiciones, servicio

En el unico if del metodo extraccionRapida no me toma el condicional (resta > limite) el IDE me suguiere soluciones que caen en error

```
package service;

import Entidades.Cliente;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClienteService {
    Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Cliente ClienteService() {
        //Instanciar un objeto de tipo vendedor
        Cliente login = new Cliente(); //el contructor vacio
        //lleno los atributos
        System.out.println("Ingrese le numero de cuenta");
        //v1.setNombre(leer.next());
        login.setNumeroCuenta(leer.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Ingrese su DNI");
        login.setDni(leer.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Ingrese su saldo actual");
        login.setSaldoActual(leer.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Ingrese el interes");
        login.setInteres(leer.nextDouble());

        return login; //revisar como se esta creando este metodo ya que deja error en el return.


    }

    public void ingreso(Cliente login) {

        System.out.println("Ingresar una cantidad de dinero");
        double ingreso = leer.nextDouble();
        double suma = ingreso + login.getSaldoActual();
        System.out.println("Se suma el dinero ingresado al Saldo actula : " + suma);


    }

    public void Retirar(Cliente login) {

        System.out.println("Retirar una cantidad de dinero");
        double retiro = leer.nextDouble();
        double resta = retiro - login.getSaldoActual();
        System.out.println("Se suma el dinero ingresado al Saldo actula : " + resta);


    }

    public void extraccionRapida(Cliente resta) {
        double limite = ClienteService().getSaldoActual() * 0.20;

        //aca va in if.
        if ( resta > limite) { //ACA ESTA EL PROBLEMA
            System.out.println("El usuario ha superado el limite del  20%");
            //limite saldo * 0.20
        }
    }
}
```

Método extraccionRapida(): le permitirá sacar solo un 20% de su saldo. Validar que el usuario no saque más del 20%.

Comment: resta es un objeto de la clase Cliente por ende debes obtener el valor "double" del sueldo para validar con el valor "double" limite , algo como resta.getSaldoActual() > limite

Comment: Buenisimo en un rato lo pruebo.

Comment: ya lo pude resolver con tu ayuda, muchas gracias!!